# Open android notification panel

Tags: android, android-notifications

How can I open the android notification panel in java code? i'd like to pull down it with a gesture in my app...

Answer (score 2):

There is no official API for this.

However, you can try doing this via reflection, but this is not guaranteed to work on all versions of Android, or on all devices running a particular version.

```
Object sbservice = getSystemService("statusbar");
Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
Method showsb = statusbarManager.getMethod("expand");
showsb.invoke(sbservice);
```

You will also need the following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
```